# Get items from a single payload using a Flux

Tags: spring, flux, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I have a method which queries a remote service. This service returns a single payload which holds many items.

How do I get those items out using a `Flux` and a `flatMapMany`?

At the moment my "fetch from service" method looks like:

```
public Flux<Stack> listAll() {
    return this.webClient
            .get()
            .uri("/projects")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .flatMapMany(response -> response.bodyToFlux(Stack.class));
}
```

a Stack is just a POJO which looks like:

```
public class Stack {
    String id;
    String name;
    String title;
    String created;
}
```

Nothing special here, but I think my deserializer is wrong:

```
protected Stack deserializeObject(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext, ObjectCodec objectCodec, JsonNode jsonNode) throws IOException {
    log.info("JsonNode {}", jsonNode);

    return Stack.builder()
            .id(nullSafeValue(jsonNode.findValue("id"), String.class))
            .name(nullSafeValue(jsonNode.findValue("name"), String.class))
            .title(nullSafeValue(jsonNode.findValue("title"), String.class))
            .created(nullSafeValue(jsonNode.findValue("created"), String.class))
            .build();
}
```

What I've noticed happening is the first object is serialized correctly, but then it seems to get serialized again, rather than the next object in the payload.

The payload coming in follows standard JSON API spec and looks like:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "type":"stacks",
         "id":"1",
         "attributes":{  
            "name":"name_1",
            "title":"title_1",
            "created":"2017-03-31 12:27:59",
            "created_unix":1490916479
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"stacks",
         "id":"2",
         "attributes":{  
            "name":"name_2",
            "title":"title_2",
            "created":"2017-03-31 12:28:00",
            "created_unix":1490916480
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"stacks",
         "id":"3",
         "attributes":{  
            "name":"name_3",
            "title":"title_3",
            "created":"2017-03-31 12:28:01",
            "created_unix":1490916481
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I've based this pattern on the [spring-reactive-university](https://github.com/bclozel/spring-reactive-university/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/integration/github/GithubIssueDeserializer.java)

Any help as to where I've gone wrong would be awesome;

Cheers!

Comment: does this webservice return a flux or just one Entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved it, still using a `Flux`.

```
public Flux<Stack> listAllStacks() {
    return this.webClient
            .get()
            .uri("/naut/projects")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(response -> response.toEntity(String.class))
            .flatMapMany(this::transformPayloadToStack);
}
```

Converts the incoming payload to a `String` where I can then parse it using a [jsonapi library](https://github.com/jasminb/jsonapi-converter)

```
private Flux<Stack> transformPayloadToStack(ResponseEntity<String> payload) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ResourceConverter resourceConverter = new ResourceConverter(objectMapper, Stack.class);
    List<Stack> stackList = resourceConverter.readDocumentCollection(payload.getBody().getBytes(), Stack.class).get();

    return Flux.fromIterable(stackList);
}
```

Which returns a `Flux`. Thanks to the library, I don't need to create a bunch of domains either, I can still work with my simple `Stack` POJO

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Type("stacks")
public class Stack {
    @com.github.jasminb.jsonapi.annotations.Id
    String id;
    String name;
    String title;
    String created;
}
```

And this in turn is called from the controller

```
@GetMapping("/stacks")
@ResponseBody
public Flux<Stack> findAll() {
    return this.stackService.listAllStacks();
}
```

I've not tested if this is blocking or not yet, but seems to work okay.

Answer (score 1):

You json doesn't exactly match with your model class i.e. Stack. Together with Stack create another class like this

```
public class Data {
  List<Stack> data;
   // Getters and Setters.... 
}
```

Now in your webclient you can do like this

```
Mono<Data> listMono = webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/product/projects")
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(Data.class));
```

Now if you do `listMono.block()` you will get Data object which will have all Stack objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will give it a go and report back. Can you explain why the example I linked works though with a flux? It's getting a single payload from github too. Also from everything I've read you're not supposed to block in anything other than tests?

Comment: regarding block, you are right, it is not advisable to do a block when doing reactive programmin. But in tests there is no other way to execute the code without block. Regarding why it is getting a single item in payload, hmmm, its a bit tricky, need to investigate more. But yes it is strange, why it fetches first item.